# What are the chances of the lunchbox contents?

Tags: fallout-shelter

What are the chances of getting rare and legendary items, and is it possible to get three legendaries or five rares in one lunchbox?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's *no* chance of getting 5 legendary or rare dwellers in one box, because the cards are fixed into categories, then the chances are divided into what you will get of those categories:

You will get:

- A Caps Card - 100 (85%)/500 Caps (15%)
- A Resource Card* - 50 power/food/water/1 stimpak/1 radaway
- A Weapon/Outfit Card - Normal (85%)/Rare (10%)/Legendary (5%)
- "Guaranteed Rare" Card* - 500 Caps/Weapon(Rare - 70%; Legendary - 30%)/Outfit(Rare - 50%; Legendary - 50%)/Dweller(rare - 90%; Legendary - 10%)

<sup>*The chance of what type of card you will get is an equal chance</sup>

> For those keeping track at home, that means you could theoretically get two MIRVs out of a single lunchbox, although the chances are pretty astronomical. I think about 1 in 1.8 million

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3m0ny9/whats_in_the_booooooxxxx_mechanics_and_statistics/)